# Plone and AngularJS routing

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, plone, plone-4.x

I'm a AngularJS newcomer and I'm trying to write some AngularJS based Plone addon.

The problem that I encountered and do not really know how to avoid is about the routing.

So, say, I've got some Plone URL, i.e. `http://localhost/blah/my_page`

This page uses AngularJS and its routing.
Clicking on some Angular managed button the user gets to `http://localhost/blah/my_page#/angular_page`
and the functionality works correctly.

This works, but only until it's refreshed. When one tries to refresh the `http://localhost/blah/my_page#/angular_page` Plone's jQuery starts complaining.

Namely, it raises the syntax error in `plone.app.jquery` (version 1.7.2), as following:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/angular_page
  m.error @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:3
  m.filter @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:3
  m @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:3
  c.querySelectorAll.m @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:3
  f.fn.extend.find @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:3
  (anonymous function) @ form_tabbing.js:166
  e.extend.each @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:2
  e.fn.e.each @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:2
  $.fn.ploneTabInit @ form_tabbing.js:157
  ploneFormTabbing.initialize @ form_tabbing.js:174
  (anonymous function) @ form_tabbing.js:179
  f.Callbacks.o @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:2
  f.Callbacks.p.fireWith @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:2
  e.extend.ready @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:2
  c.addEventListener.B @ ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js:2
```

Plone's jQuery seems to validate the URL and the Angular's part does not match it.

What is the best way to avoid the problem?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone faced the same issue, I've eventually found the solution.

The root cause of a problem was in the `form_tabbing.js` file, and the following code in the `ploneTabInit` function:

```
 var targetPane = item.find('.enableFormTabbing input[name="fieldset"]').val() || window.location.hash;
    if (targetPane) {
        item.find(".enableFormTabbing .formTabs " +
         targetPane.replace("'", "").replace(/^#fieldset-/, "#fieldsetlegend-")).click();
    }
```

the `window.location.hash` was assigned to `targetPane`, hence the issue.
It triggered the search of this value using jQuery's Sizzle search engine.
The search like `$('#/something')` raises syntax error.

Disabling form_tabbing.js in this particular view was enough for me.